# Python Widget with SizePolicy

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qwidget, qsizepolicy

Why the sizePolicy doesn't affect on widgets that aren't in layout?

here is an example:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)

test_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(window)
test_widget.setMinimumSize(100, 100)
test_widget.setStyleSheet("background-color:red")
size_policy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
test_widget.setSizePolicy(size_policy)


window.show()
app.exec()
```

But that doesn't work, if you changed the main window size the red box still has the same size.

So how can I make that red box resizeable when the parent (main window) is changing.

**NOTE:** I don't want to use Layouts for some reason.

Comment: "I don't want to use Layouts for some reason." And what reason would that be? Besides, you're setting a size policy without using a layout manager, and every size policy reference in the docs explicitly mentions that it relates to layout: [`sizePolicy()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop) ("This property holds the default layout behavior of the widget") the QSizePolicy [summary](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html) ("The QSizePolicy class is a layout attribute") and its detailed description ("The size policy of a widget [...] affects how the widget is treated by the layout engine").

Comment: "And what reason would that be? " Because I have a design and I think it can't be achieved without using this following approach: the GUI should have Canvas (for drawing shapes) in the back (I mean taking the whole size of the parent-widget) AND some Menus (Widgets) will be in front of that canvas. So the canvas will be added to the widget and those menus will be added to the grid layout of the parent_widget

Comment: If I added the canvas to GridLayout as well as the menus, it won't take the whole size of that widget

Comment: The geometry of a widget is managed either by a layout *or* 'manually', i.e. by your own code.  So if you don't want to use a layout then it's up to you to override the parent's `QWidget::resizeEvent` etc. to manage the child widgets geometry accordingly.

Comment: @G.M. Thank you. And do you think this is a good approach? did you check my previous comments that why am using this, What is your opinion, I have no clue with qt.

Comment: @Moaaz for future reference, always try to explain *why* you're doing something: "for some reason" is almost always the *wrong* reason (and, in fact, it's your case), and usually leads to asking the wrong question (see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). Also note that you can still use a layout for your "main widget" and add a "floating" widget that you can then resize in the `resizeEvent()` as explained above. Some related examples: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70350069/2001654 https://stackoverflow.com/a/70631192/2001654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your GUI design but you should note that a single cell (as defined by a row/column pair) in a `QGridLayout` can be occupied by more than a single widget.  A (very) simple example demonstrates this...

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGridLayout, QLabel, QPushButton, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt

class widget(QWidget):
    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(widget, self).__init__(parent)
        gl = QGridLayout(self)
        pb = QPushButton("Show/Hide Menu")
        self.menu = QLabel("Menu goes here...")
        self.menu.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: #40800000;")
        canvas = QLabel("Canvas")
        canvas.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        canvas.setStyleSheet("background-color: #40000080;")
        gl.addWidget(pb, 0, 0)
        gl.addWidget(canvas, 0, 0, 2, 2)
        pb.raise_()
        pb.clicked.connect(self.toggle_menu)
        gl.addWidget(self.menu, 1, 0)
        self.menu.hide()
    def toggle_menu (self, checked):
        self.menu.setVisible(not self.menu.isVisible())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    w = widget()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[I've used `PySide2` as I don't have `PyQt5` installed.]

So if I *have* understood correctly then I don't see why you can't make use of a `QGridLayout`.  Could save you a lot of work.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that I can add a cell that takes the whole grid and I can add other cells on it :D